# Why isn't this thread working?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm a beginning Java programmer. I'm trying to construct a Space Invaders game that can be played directly in the console. Later, I would like to add a graphical interface through JFrame; however, at this time, I have restricted myself to creating a non-functional JFrame window. I have the classes saved in a few files - Constants.java, Entity.java, Player.java, and Board.java, SpaceInvaders.java - and I have compiled these files in the specified order. My problem is that when I attempt to run the main method, nothing is shown. No window pops up. No output is displayed in the console. I suspect that the problem lies in the class Board, perhaps in the thread construction in the method gameInit() or in the method run(). I cannot find any information regarding threads in my course textbook - I obtained the thread code from the website http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javagamestutorial/spaceinvaders/ and I will cite it in my final version of the project.

Do let me know if you can offer me any pointers. I apologize for my lack of familiarity with the formatting of stackoverflow.com.

I've enclosed a copy of my code below.

Constants.java

```
import java.io.*;

public interface Constants {
    public static final int MOTION_WIDTH = 20;
    public static final int MOTION_LENGTH = 20;
    public static final int DELAY = 17;
}
```

---

Entity.java

```
import java.io.*;

public class Entity {
    private int xPosition;
    private int yPosition;

    public void setXPosition(int newXPosition) {
        this.xPosition = newXPosition;
    }

    public int getXPosition() {
        return xPosition;
    }

    public void setYPosition(int newYPosition) {
        this.yPosition = newYPosition;
    }

    public int getYPosition() {
        return yPosition;
    }
}
```

---

Player.java

```
import java.io.*;

import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class Player extends Entity implements Constants{
    private final int START_X_POSITION = 0;
    private final int START_Y_POSITION = 0;
    int x = 0; 

    public Player() {
        setXPosition(START_X_POSITION);
        setYPosition(START_Y_POSITION);
    }

    public void move() {
        setXPosition((getXPosition()) + x);

        if ((getXPosition()) <= 0) {
            setXPosition(0);
        }
        if ((getXPosition()) >= MOTION_WIDTH) {
            setXPosition(MOTION_WIDTH);
        }
    }
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            x = 1;
        } else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            x = -1;
        }
        }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            x = 0;
        } else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            x = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Board.java

```
import java.io.*;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;

public class Board extends JPanel implements Runnable, Constants {
    Player player;
    boolean gameRunning = true;
    Thread animator;

    char[][] motion = new char[MOTION_WIDTH][MOTION_LENGTH];


    public Board() {
        addKeyListener(new KeyListener());
        setFocusable(true);     
        gameInit();
        setDoubleBuffered(true);
    }

//Ensure that I cite this
    public void addNotify() {
        super.addNotify();
        gameInit();
    }

    public void gameInit() {

        player = new Player();

        for (int i = 0; i < MOTION_WIDTH; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < MOTION_LENGTH; j++) {
                    motion[i][j] = '0';
            }
        }

        motion[0][0] = '^';


            if (animator == null) {
                    animator = new Thread(this);
                    animator.start();
            }
    }
    private class KeyListener extends KeyAdapter {
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            player.keyPressed(e);
        }
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            player.keyReleased(e);
        }
    }

    public void paint() {

        for (int i = 0; i < MOTION_WIDTH; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < MOTION_LENGTH; j++) {
                    motion[i][j] = '0';
            }
        }       

        motion[player.getXPosition()][player.getYPosition()] = '^';

        for (int i = 0; i < MOTION_WIDTH; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < MOTION_LENGTH; j++) {
                System.out.print(motion[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public void animationCycle() {
        player.move();
        paint();
    }
//Ensure that I cite this
    public void run() {
        long beforeTime, timeDiff, sleep;

        beforeTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        while (gameRunning) {
            paint();
            animationCycle();

            timeDiff = System.currentTimeMillis() - beforeTime;
            sleep = DELAY - timeDiff;

            if (sleep < 0) 
                sleep = 2;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(sleep);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("interrupted");
            }
            beforeTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
    }
}
```

---

SpaceInvaders.java

```
import java.io.*;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;

public class SpaceInvaders extends JFrame implements Constants {
    public void SpaceInvaders() {
        add(new Board());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(500, 500);
        setVisible(true);
        requestFocusInWindow();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            new SpaceInvaders();
    }
}
```

Comment: `public void SpaceInvaders()` is not a constructor. Try removing the `void` from that line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the class `SpaceInvaders` the constructor you provided is not really a constructor. Please remove the return-type `void`. So it should read

```
public SpaceInvaders() {
    add(new Board());
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(500, 500);
    setVisible(true);
    requestFocusInWindow();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpaceInvaders();
}
```

Here is an info on constructors from the Java docs:

> A class contains constructors that are invoked to create objects from the class blueprint. Constructor declarations look like method declarations—except that they use the name of the class and have no return type. 
>   (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html)

With the modification applied the JFrame shows up and also a lot of 0 and a ^ are printed on the console.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the thread start in your code. I think you have to start the thread as below example

```
class Board implements Runnable{  
public void run(){  
System.out.println("thread is running...");  
}  

public static void main(String args[]){  
Board b1=new Board();  
Thread t1 =new Thread(b1);  
t1.start();  
 }  
}
```

And also the construct should not have the return type

```
public void SpaceInvaders() {
}
```

change to

```
public SpaceInvaders() {
}
```

Comment: My Bad I have not seen that thank you, Stefan Freitag